# stdole.dll has already loaded from a different location?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build a solution composed of multiple projects in Visual Studio 2010, but one of the projects is giving me a strange error when I compile it:

```
Cannot load referenced assembly: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\stdole\7.0.3300.0_b03f5f711d50a3a\stdole.dll
System.IO.FileLoadException - API restriction: The assembly 'file:\\\<same as above>' has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain.
```

At first I though I would need to remove this stdole.dll reference, so I deleted it. However, after deleting it, I get the following error instead:

> The type or namespace 'stdole' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Adding the reference back again gave the first error again.

I understand why I get the last error, but I don't understand why I'm getting the first. I'm fairly new at .NET, and am the only one remaining at my current company with any experience with C#, meaning that there's no one here who can help me. I've also spent some time trying to look up a solution online, but my lack of experience in this domain is making it hard for me to find an answer I can understand.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you reference any other component that in turn references stdole which is loaded previously and takes the system version while you copied your stdole locally? You could try to analyse with systinternals tools (FileMon) where stdole is loaded from, maybe this helps.

Comment: @Sascha No, and in fact I tried to simply create a project with only stdole referenced in it, and it still gave me the same error. I'm going to try "uninstalling"/removing stdole and "reinstalling" it to see if this problem is still occuring.

Comment: Only solution that works for me is removing the reference and readding it. The problem eventually comes back, but it seems only when I branch the code and pull it back down from source control.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly add reference to file by address for example:

C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\stdole\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\stdole.dll

Not from GAC (Registered Assemblies)

Comment: This ultimately solved it for me. Visual studio told me it couldn't find the file at some location so I went to add references > browse > chose stdole from the location it was complaining about.